# Error Log Events 137 and 108 when click on subscription

Tags: power-bi-report-server

when i click on the subscription Link in any report, or Setting-Subscription the server logs 12 error log entries in application log with no specific information inside. Four with eventid 137 and eight with 108.
I checked the log files (RSPortal* and RSPowerBI*) but there´s only INFO lines at the point of error log events. Each subscription works fine after configuration.

(PowerBI RS Version : 1.6.7364.4075 - Jan 2020)

Does anyone have an idea where I could get more detailed information about this problem here?
Thank for helping

Wilfried